# MMQGIS returns city locations instead of addresses

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

I've been trying to geocode addresses using MMQGIS. In each case, the .shp file has a point over where the name of the city is located on the Google Maps OpenLayers map, instead of at the location of the address.

I fed the program a csv file with the following addresses:

```
Address City    State

6 Dorset Ct East Brunswick  NJ
702 Washington Dr   Ramsey  NJ
293 Washington Ave  Brooklyn    NY
1400 Laurel Ave Minneapolis MN
```

Here is the MMQGIS window:
[image]

Comment: i see the MMQGIS dialogue reading the column names, but the addresses you've posted don't look like CSV, rather Tab separated... is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate the CSV file using a comma with the correct position for separating Address, City, and State.

```
Address, City,    State

6 Dorset Ct, East Brunswick,  NJ
702 Washington Dr,   Ramsey,  NJ
293 Washington Ave,  Brooklyn,    NY
1400 Laurel Ave, Minneapolis, MN
```

then you can use MMQGIS to input the CSV file correctly, and use Google Web Service to give you the address.

Here is the output of the first address:

[image]